Is this convex set open?
Let $X$ be a normed space over $\mathbb{R}$, and let $K \subset X$ be a convex subset with the property that, for every $u \in X, u \neq 0$ there exists $M(u) > 0$ such that
$ \{ \lambda \in \mathbb{R} : \lambda u \in K \} = (-M(u), M(u))$.
Is this set open? My intuition tells me that it must be, but I can't find a way to show it.

@BenjaminKuykendall thanks for catching that, I misread the question as on the reals.

Thank you for checking the answer. I updated it with a cleaner argument, so please check if interested.

Rather than the original statement, I will show the following argument instead:

Proposition 1. $K$ is open or nowhere dense $(\mathrm{int}_X(\bar{K})=\emptyset)$.
Here, the former is precisely the case when $0\in \mathrm{int}_X(K)$.

Therefore, $\mathrm{int}_X(K)$ is either $K$ or $\emptyset$.
Intuitively, the latter case means $K$ is infinitely flat. This is only possible when $X$ is infinite-dimensional. Consider the Hilbert space $\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ and the convex set:
$$
S = (-1, 1) \times (-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) \times \ldots \subset \ell_2(\mathbb{N}).
$$
Then $S$ satisfies the setting. However, $S$ is not an open subset of $\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ because the $0 \notin \mathrm{int}_X(S)$. Checking given set has closure $\bar{S}= [-1, 1] \times [-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}] \times \ldots$ and $\mathrm{int}_X(\bar{S}) = \emptyset$ are also straightforward.
Before starting the proof, let us check some observations:

Observeation 1.  The closure $\bar{K}$ is also convex set, and $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}: \lambda u\in \pmb{\bar{K}}\} = \big[\!-\!M(u)\,,\, M(u)\,\big]$.
Observation 2. $K$ is nowhere dense ($\mathrm{int}_X(K)=\emptyset$) iff $0 \notin \mathrm{int}_X(K)$.

To check Obs.2, assume to the contrary, let $u\in \mathrm{int}_X(\bar{K})$ is an interior point and $0 \notin \mathrm{int}_X(K)$. Then, an open set $U$ that $u \in U \subset \bar{K}$ exists. By Obs.1, $-U$ and $V = \frac{1}{2}U + \frac{1}{2}(-U)$ are open sets in $\bar{K}$. Finally, since $\frac{1}{2}V$ is an open set in $K$ containing the origin, we derive contradiction to the assumption that the origin is not an interior point of $K$.  $\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$
Thanks to Obs.2, the only left to prove is the following argument:

Left to show: If $0 \in \mathrm{int}_X(K)$, $K$ is an open set.

proof)
First, from the assumption that $0\in K$ is an interior point, $\delta>0$ exists, such that $B(0,\delta)\subset K$. This can be equally stated as $M|_{\partial B(0,1)} : \partial B(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is (strictly) lower bounded by $\delta$.
Consider the function $\phi: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ defined as:
$$
\phi(u) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{M(u)} = \frac{\|u\|}{M|_{\partial B(0,1)}(\pi(u))}  & u \neq 0 \\
0 & u = 0
\end{cases}
\,,
$$
where $\pi$ is canonical contraction $\pi: X-\{0\} \rightarrow \partial B(0,1)$, therefore $\pi(u) = \frac{u}{\|u\|}$.
Since $M|_{\partial B(0,1)}$ has a nonzero lower bound, it is easy to see that $\phi$ is (1) continuous at the origin. Furthermore, by the convexity of $K$ and original problem setting, $\phi$ is (2) positive homogeneous and (3) sub-additive. Aggregating the observation, it can be shown that $\phi$ is indeed a continuous function.
Now, consider the function $\Phi: X \rightarrow X$ as:
$$
\Phi(u) = {
\begin{cases}
\phi(u) \pi(u) = \phi(u) \frac{u}{\| u\|} = \frac{u}{M|_{\partial B(0,1)}(\pi(u))} & u \neq 0 \\
0 & u = 0
\end{cases}}\,.
$$
Then, $\Phi$ becomes a continuous function. By observing that $u\in K-\{0\} \Longleftrightarrow M(u)>1$, we get $K = \Phi^{-1}\!\big(B(0,1)\big)$.
Finally, $K$ is an open set because it is an inverse image of an open ball on a continuous function.
